# Add span in wordpress menu

Tags: html, wordpress, markup

I want to add a `<span>` in wordpress menu just after `<a>` tag so that it should look like this

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-13">
<a href="http://wordpress.org/"><span>Home</span></a>
</li>
```

Any help and suggestions will be appreciable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hey thanks for your reply but I got it. It should be like this

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'link_before' => '<span>','link_after'=>'</span>' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score -4):

It in the following file :

/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php

html output starts on line 82

Let's be nice, here's the code, replace from line 82 to 109 :

```
    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</span></a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}

/**
 * @see Walker::end_el()
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param object $item Page data object. Not used.
 * @param int $depth Depth of page. Not Used.
 */
function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth) {
    $output .= "</li>\n";
}
```

}

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply but I got it. It should be like this
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'link_before' => '<span>','link_after'=>'</span>' ) ); ?>

Comment: Also, you should never edit core WordPress files like that. If you do an autoupdate, all your changes will be lost and potentially break the site.